# Trying to add Django Countries to Django

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to django and I am trying to install django countries and am haveing issues.  I Installed from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries/1.0.1.  When I installed, I put it into this folder.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/django_countries
```

I then added django_countries to the the list of isntalled apps as follows.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
    'django.contrib.django_counties',
    'polls',
    'rthui',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

when I ran the below I get the below error

```
python manage.py syncdb
Error: No module named django_counties
```

So...what diod I do wrong?  What else am I supped to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this version was downloaded from google, it looks like the app is in a subfolder called countries.  Put this folder in your python dist-packages folder so the path is /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/countries and then add countries to the list of installed apps.  See this doc for more details http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL.txt

Comment: where is the django site directory?

Comment: When I placed the countires in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/countries... I get this error--> Error: cannot import name settings

Comment: I have it installed.  Created a table.  Now trying to create a DDL in my model but jsut dont get it.  from countries import CountryField and then trying to do country = CountryField() in my model. I owuld love to ss a ddl in my admin for the table.

Comment: I ended up using country = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=countries.COUNTRIES) with from countries import countries

Answer (score 4):

Why did you put it into `django.contrib`? That's for apps that are supplied with Django.

Install it properly, into its own directory. Then, fix the spelling error you have made in INSTALLED_APPS: `countries`, not `counties`.

Comment: I removed the dir in contrib.  So...it is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_countries-1.0.1-py2.7.egg.  I then have django_countries in the installed apps.  I get  the same error when doing a sync.

Comment: Te misspelling was not the problem.  Its misspelled in this post..not the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install django countries with this command:

```
sudo pip install django-countries
```

Then your INSTALLED_APPS should be updated like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3',
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'django_countries',
)
```

(note: no django. prefix, countries spelt correctly, underscore not dash)

BTW I found this command useful when verifying package names:

```
pip list
```