# django-countries: Person() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the [django-countries application](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) with Django for the first time but I am getting this error which has me confused.

```
TypeError at /survey/

Person() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I installed django-countries 2.1.2 via pip in a virtual environment for the project.

**INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'survey',
    'django_countries',
)
```

I am using Django 1.6.4.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Person(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from models import SexChoice, AgeChoice, RelationshipStatusChoice, Person

def Person(request):

    age = AgeChoice()
    sex = SexChoice()
    relationship = RelationshipStatusChoice()   
    country = Person()

    return render(request, 'survey.html', {
                                           'age': age,
                                           'sex': sex,
                                           'relationship': relationship,     
                                           'country': country,                                      
                                           })
```

**survy.html**

```
<html> 
    <body>

        <h1>Experiment Survey</h1>

            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>What age are you?</h3>
                    {{age.as_p}}

                <h3>What sex are you?</h3>
                    {{sex.as_p}}

                <h3>What is your current relationship status?</h3>
                    {{relationship.as_p}}

                <h3>What country are you from?</h3>

                    {{country.as_p}}

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />               
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. This is similar to an earlier question but I fixed a few issues and updated some details. I deleted the earlier question.

Answer (score 1):

Your model **and** your view has the same name so you have a namespace conflict. Change the name of the view and it will be fine.

The error says you need to pass an argument because you have redefined `Person` to be a function with 1 argument (`request`). Something like this should work (adapt your `urls.py`):

```
def create_survey(request): 
     # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as with the above you were also correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have Person the model class and Person the function.  Name one of them something else (and functions should not start with capitals anyway).

Looks like Person the function requires a `request` parameter, which you're not passing in.  I think you mean to be using Person the class, but the redefinition is confusing things.

Comment: First step done, and thanks for the tip regarding naming convention. I renamed the function 'survey' - The page is now displaying with the other drop downs but the country list is not displaying.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `origin` variable instead of `country` based on how you defined them? (`origin = CountryChoice()` but then further down `'country': country` - you never pass it to the webpage)

Comment: Do you need to import CountryChoice?

Comment: @TyrantWave & @ thumbtackthief No, that's a different working country choice field i have working with 5 countries in it. I want to get the 'django-countries' app working to replace it so i don't have to hand code in circa 200 countries. Ill edit the question to remove the reference.

Comment: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258914/trying-to-add-django-countries-to-django is it possible that i am not referencing the package correctly in the INSTALLED_APPS ? I am using 'django_countries', NOTE i installed via PIP in a virtual enviroment

Comment: I am currently getting no Error message. The survey.html page is displaying but the django_countries `{{countries.as_p}}` is not displaying. Thanks

Comment: `{{country.as_p}}` or `{{countries.as_p}}`?