# django-countries dropdown not displaying

Tags: python, django

[This is the third iteration of this question as errors have been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725477/django-countries-person-takes-exactly-1-argument-0-given) (with the grateful help of a few people). To avoid confusion about what exactly is happening I felt it was necessary to re-post with updated details.

I am using Django 1.6.4.

I am trying to use the [django-countries application](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) with Django but the drop down is not being displayed. I am getting no errors, but the below survey.html page is not showing the expected dropdown of ISO 3166-1 list of countries.

I installed django-countries 2.1.2 via pip in a virtual environment for the project. It has been added to the installed apps

**INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'survey',
    'django_countries',
)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Person(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from models import SexChoice, AgeChoice, RelationshipStatusChoice, Person

def survey(request):

    age = AgeChoice()
    sex = SexChoice()
    relationship = RelationshipStatusChoice()   
    country = Person()

    return render(request, 'survey.html', {
                                           'age': age,
                                           'sex': sex,
                                           'relationship': relationship,     
                                           'country': country,                                      
                                           })
```

**survy.html**

```
<html> 
    <body>

        <h1>Experiment Survey</h1>

            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>What age are you?</h3>
                    {{age.as_p}}

                <h3>What sex are you?</h3>
                    {{sex.as_p}}

                <h3>What is your current relationship status?</h3>
                    {{relationship.as_p}}

                <h3>What country are you from?</h3>

                    {{country.as_p}}

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />               
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought this would give me a `country.as_p` drop down but I am seeing nothing. I do not get any errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries), there is a tuple of 2-tuple available in the module to fill your field:

> #### Get the countries from Python
>
> Use the `django_countries.countries` object instance as an iterator of ISO 3166-1 country codes and names (sorted by name).

So the following should work:

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django_countries import countries

class Person(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(choices=list(countries))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country
```

EDIT: After discussion, it comes that I totally mixed up by reading too fast the OP code. In fact, you need to create a `Form` and not using your models directly in your template:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    age = forms.CharField()
    sex = forms.CharField()
    relationship = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.CountryField(choices=list(countries))

#####

def survey(request):
    form = SurveyForm()

    return render(request, 'survey.html', {'form': form})


#####

My whole form:
{{ form.as_p }}
```

As I said in chat, [further explication are available in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Comment: @ Maxime Lorant Thanks, this is my first time trying to import a third party package so forgive me. Unfortunately I keep getting an error though. "  File "/documents/workspace/experiment/src/survey/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES
ImportError: No module named countries" Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have the last version of `django-countries`? It seems older version didn't have the `countries.py` file... The 1.0.1 version does ;)

Comment: typing "pip freeze" tells me its "django-countries==2.1.2" I believe this is the latest version.

Comment: Alright, fixed it I was looking to the wrong version... Kind of confusing

Comment: Thanks ;-) I am now getting no errors but it is still not displaying in the survey.html page.

Comment: Damn. Can you try with `list(countries)` then? :-) I am getting a list of 2-tuple in my console as asked by the `choices` parameter.

Comment: I have tried it with "country = CountryField(list(countries))" this has no effect. "country = CountryField.list(countries)" gives an error "AttributeError: type object 'CountryField' has no attribute 'list'" Am I missing somthing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53918/discussion-between-maxime-lorant-and-deepend)

Answer (score 3):

You need this form:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    age = forms.CharField()
    sex = forms.CharField()
    relationship = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=list(countries))
```

Not you need to use ChoiceField() in the form class. CountryField() is used for the model.