# How do I refer to packages installed via pip in a virtual enviroment in INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: django

When I create a new app in a Django project via `python manage.py startapp polls` I then simply add it to my list of installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'survy',
)
```

However when I install an application such as [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) via PIP `pip install django-countries` into a virtual environment is there a different or better way to add it to the list of installed apps?

I have simply been using the same method and I think it might be wrong, thus contributing to the issue  having in my other question.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'survey',
    'django_countries',
)
```

This is giving me no errors but I am not sure if it working right.

NOTE: as per the [pip page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258914/trying-to-add-django-countries-to-django), the package is called `django-countries` but I believe it should be referred to as `django_countries` in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: No, you are right. You just need to add the module name, as if it was one of your module.

Comment: Thanks, If you can put that in an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Done with some explication :)

Comment: That would have solved my original question but unfortunately not. Nice to have confirmation though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are right. You just need to add the module name, as if it was one of your module.

Django searches apps in your Python path and it will take the first module it find. Since Django third-parties are installed in `site-packages` generally (the one of the virtualenv in your case) and this folder is in your Python path, Django will act as usual with these modules.